# Lotus Domino Designer: Add a button in the default calendar

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I need to add a button to the calendar by default.

This button is a http link.

Like this:

[image]

Any idea ? I begin with Lotus Domino Designer.

Comment: Does the button have to be in the position you show it?  Or is it okay to put it next to the "Verifier l'agenda" button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locate the view you are seeing in the designer, and add an [Action button](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATING_A_FORM_OR_VIEW_ACTION.html) to the action bar.

To have the action open an url, make it a "Formla" action and use the [@URLOpen](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_URLOPEN.html) formula

```
@URLOpen("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```